# Movie where a lady is shot and left for dead in some trees but is saved and turned into a robot

Tags: story-identification, movie, cyborg

All I call remember of this film was a lady with dark hair was running through some trees and a few men were chasing her. They shot her a lot and left her for dead. Someone found her and in order to save her life turned most of her into a robot.

The only other part of the movie I can remember is her in an office and the guy is telling her to slowly turn around to look at the room. He then told her to close her eyes and recall what the third book on the second shelf is called. Which I'm paraphrasing. She said it can't be done and they argue about it but when she does it she can tell him what the book was.

It is in English and I would be guessing but I'm thinking it was made in the 90's or early 2000's.

Comment: Can you tell us where you saw this movie, when it might have been made, what language it was is, production values etc. Any detail you could add can help us help you @)

Comment: Also, Welcome to SF&F Stack Exchange!  If you haven't already, you should take the [tour] and read the [FAQ].

Comment: It is in English and I would be guessing but I'm thinking it was made in the 90's or early 2000's

Answer (score 6):

Sci-fi thriller [Running Delilah](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0111035/) with Kim Cattrall & Billy Zane from 1993.

> Top agent Delilah (Kim Cattrall) dies in a risky mission against weapon dealer Alec Kasharian (Yorgo Voyagis). But she's revived with high-tech medicine and artificial body parts.

Everything you mentioned is there. She's shot in the woods, and later a scientist tells her to scan the room around her and specify a certain book on the shelf. The film is currently available on Youtube [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CLRnL-UE9qs), and here's the poster from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Running_Delilah):

[image]